# Logitech K750 not working

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, hardware

I brought new Logitech K750 keyboard. When I insert wireless unifying receiver to my laptop, I was expecting that some software utility will pop up for installation but all in vain. I rebooted the system, Nothing happened, I type key on keyboard but it doesn't take any input and system shows no response. I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Any suggestions on how to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Logitech keyboards should work out of box with unifying transmitter. But if you have to configure it manually, you should install the "solaar" package.

#### Installation

```
sudo apt-get install solaar solaar-gnome3
```

If you are running Ubuntu before 16.04, you have to add repository before:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel.pavel/solaar
sudo apt-get update
```

#### How to use

The "solaar-gnome3" package provides a gnome application which can be used to add or remove devices from Logitech's Unifying dongle

Comment: Hi @Zanna, I edited my answer with a short summary on how to install and use solaar. If you need more help, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any installation utility that pops up, since Logitech doesn't really support Linux.  But normally, their USB devices work fine with Linux (I use a Logitech standard infra-red USB mouse).  I have heard of at least one user who uses the K750 with Ubuntu in the past.

Is the one you have USB?  If so, do you get any indication at all when you plug it in?  Have you tried any other USB slots?  If you're using a USB-3 slot, you may need to switch to USB-2, as there are sometimes compatibility issues.

If it doesn't work, then you might be out of luck.  Logitech isn't too good about Linux support, I don't think.